# A function to fill in a column with NA of the same type

Tags: r, dplyr, na

I have a data frame with many columns of different types. I would like to replace each column with NA of the corresponding class.

for example:

```
df = data_frame(x = c(1,2,3), y = c("a", "b", "c"))

df[, 1:2] <- NA
```

yields a data frame with two logical columns, rather than numeric and character.
I know I can tell R:

```
df[,1] = as.numeric(NA)
df[,2] = as.character(NA)
```

But how do I do this collectively in a loop for all columns with all possible types of NA?

Comment: Good question +1, but why does this matter?

Comment: It's a very weird problem, I later need to join the data frame with another frame of the original type...

Comment: But why? Please give us more context, seems like pointless (but fun) step.

Comment: I have a data frame created in the beginning of my program, which sometimes need to get all NA's in some columns based on a condition. This data frame needs to be joined with another data frame in the end of the program, which might not get these NA's. In order for the join to work, the two data frames need to have exactly the same types of columns.

Comment: Just a minor correction, you shouldn't talk about classes here but about atomic types, and it would be more idiomatic to use `NA_character_` and `NA_numeric_` than `as.character(NA)` and `as.numeric(NA)`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use this "trick" :

```
df[1:nrow(df),1] <- NA
df[1:nrow(df),2] <- NA
```

the `[1:nrow(df),]` basically tells R to *replace* all values in the column with `NA` and in this way the logical `NA` is coerced to the original type of the column before replacing the other values.

Also, if you have a lot of columns to replace and the data_frame has a lot of rows, I suggest to store the row indexes and reuse them :

```
rowIdxs <- 1:nrow(df)
df[rowIdxs ,1] <- NA
df[rowIdxs ,2] <- NA
df[rowIdxs ,3] <- NA
...
```

---

As cleverly suggested by [@RonakShah](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3962914/ronak-shah), you can also use :

```
df[TRUE, 1] <- NA
df[TRUE, 2] <- NA
...
```

---

As pointed out by [@Cath](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4137985/cath) both the methods still work when you select more than one column e.g. :

```
df[TRUE, 1:3] <- NA
# or
df[1:nrow(df), 1:3] <- NA
```

Comment: Awesome... so simple :)

Comment: why not directly `df[TRUE, 1:2] <- NA`?

Answer (score 8):

Another solution that applies to **all** the columns can be to specify the non-NAs and replace with NA, i.e.

```
df[!is.na(df)] <- NA
```

which gives,

> ```
> # A tibble: 3 x 2
>       x    y    
>   <dbl> <chr>
> 1    NA <NA> 
> 2    NA <NA> 
> 3    NA <NA>
> ```

Answer (score 6):

Another way to change all columns at once while keeping the variables' classes:

```
df[] <- lapply(df, function(x) {type <- class(x); x <- NA; class(x) <- type; x})

df
# A tibble: 3 x 2
#      x y    
#  <dbl> <chr>
#1    NA <NA> 
#2    NA <NA> 
#3    NA <NA>
```

---

As @digEmAll notified in comments, there is another similar but shorter way:

```
df[] <- lapply(df, function(x) as(NA,class(x)))
```

Comment: Also `lapply(df, function(x)as(NA,class(x)))` should work

Comment: another base option `df[] <- lapply(df, replace, TRUE, NA)`

Comment: This works in many cases, but not always. The problem is that some classes don't have methods that automatically convert the underlying `typeof`, and sometimes `as` doesn't know how to handle classes.
Try it with a `POSIXct`: `as` throws an error, and manually setting the class to `c("POSIXt", "POSIXct")` seems to work, but does not convert the underlying NA, the result is different then `as.POSIXct(NA)`

Comment: It would be better to use `typeof` instead of `class`, here it works "by chance" but will fail in the general case (e.g. factors).

Comment: as OP seems to be a tidyverse user, this would be suitable as well : `df <- modify(df,~as(NA,typeof(.)))`

Answer (score 4):

Using *dplyr::na_if*:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  mutate(x = na_if(x, x),
         y = na_if(y, y))

# # A tibble: 3 x 2
#       x y    
#   <dbl> <chr>
# 1    NA NA   
# 2    NA NA   
# 3    NA NA
```

If we want to mutate only subset of columns to *NA*, then:

```
# dataframe with extra column that stay unchanged
df = data_frame(x = c(1,2,3), y = c("a", "b", "c"), z = c(4:6))

df %>% 
  mutate_at(vars(x, y), funs(na_if(.,.)))

# # A tibble: 3 x 3
#       x y         z
#   <dbl> <chr> <int>
# 1    NA NA        4
# 2    NA NA        5
# 3    NA NA        6
```

Comment: Or `df <- mutate_all(df,~na_if(.,.))` (or `modify(df,~na_if(.,.))`) while you're there :)

Comment: @Moody_Mudskipper I am using `mutate_at` as OP might want to do this on subset of columns. If they want to apply this to all columns, then why not just create an empty dataframe with 0 rows...

Comment: I don't know... OP's use case is obscure, but he mentions replacing each column by NAs.

Answer (score 0):

Using `bind_cols()` from `dplyr` you can also do:

```
df <- data_frame(x = c(1,2,3), y = c("a", "b", "c"))
classes <- sapply(df, class)
df[,1:2] <- NA

bind_cols(lapply(colnames(x), function(x){eval(parse(text=paste0("as.", classes[names(classes[x])], "(", df[,x],")")))}))

     V1 V2   
  <dbl> <chr>
1    NA NA   
2    NA NA   
3    NA NA
```

Please note that this will change the colnames.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach using`dplyr`:

```
df <- tibble(x = c(1,2,3), y = c("a", "b", "c")) 
df
#> # A tibble: 3 x 2
#>       x y    
#>   <dbl> <chr>
#> 1     1 a    
#> 2     2 b    
#> 3     3 c

df %>% 
  mutate(across(everything(), ~as(NA, class(.x))))
#> # A tibble: 3 x 2
#>       x y    
#>   <dbl> <chr>
#> 1    NA <NA> 
#> 2    NA <NA> 
#> 3    NA <NA>
```